# How to define a dictionary like structure in Oracle PL SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, varray

How to define in PL/SQL the following structure:

**A list of strings which contains multiple rows.**

Example:

```
'User A'
    -->
        (1)
            -->
                1
        (2)
            -->
                2


'User B'
    -->
        (1)
            -->
                0
        (2)
            -->
                9
```

The integers are defined as:

```
TYPE number_arry IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

How to define the whole structure ?

I want to fill this structure from this table:

```
RowId | User_A | User_B  
------+--------+--------
1     |      1 |      0
2     |      2 |      0
3     |      3 |      9
```

With these statements:

```
CURSOR c1
        IS
            SELECT User_A, User_B FROM my_table;

OPEN c1;
    LOOP
        FETCH c1
          BULK COLLECT INTO
                my_dict('User A'),
                my_dict('User B')

        LIMIT 1000;

        EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the following structure:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE my_table AS
  2     SELECT 1 user_a, 0 user_b FROM dual
  3     UNION ALL SELECT 2, 0 FROM dual
  4     UNION ALL SELECT 3, 9 FROM dual;

Table created

SQL> DECLARE
  2     CURSOR c1 IS
  3        SELECT User_A, User_B FROM my_table;
  4     TYPE number_arry IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  5     TYPE dictionary_type IS TABLE OF number_arry INDEX BY VARCHAR2(30);
  6     l_dico dictionary_type;
  7  BEGIN
  8     OPEN c1;
  9     LOOP
 10        FETCH c1 BULK COLLECT
 11           INTO l_dico('User A'), l_dico('User B') LIMIT 1000;
 12        EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
 13     END LOOP;
 14     CLOSE c1;
 15  END;
 16  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Comment: Hi Vincent, thanks for your response, however, I did post the wrong question, I've updated the description, can you please take a look again ?